# Conditionally render icon which is type of Styled Component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I have 2 svg images. I want to use them as hamburger menu icons - if the menu is opened I want to display close icon, and if it is not, to use hamburger menu icon. I am sending this as prop.

```
 <Hamburger onClick={navHandler} isOpen={isOpen} />
```

In other words, to have this

[image]

or this

[image]

This is the code I have:

[image]

I tried to do it like this, but it did not work

```
export const Hamburger = styled(({ isOpen}) => (isOpen? CloseIcon : HamburgerIcon))`
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that `isOpen` is a `useState` variable then this should work:

```
import { ReactComponent as CloseIcon } from 'assets/close.svg';
import { ReactComponent as HamburgerIcon } from 'assets/hamburger.svg';

{isOpen && <CloseIcon />}
{!isOpen && <HamburgerIcon />}
```

Note that I'm sharing with you the technique that me and my team uses to import images and define them as React components.  It works really well.

P.S. I forget the precise rules, but there are limitations on how complex the logic to render one thing for this state or another thing for another state.